# align items equal using flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

hii I have a simple section which displays  list of data right side and left side, I want to look like this[image]

here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Mwanitete/ukxavqwn/33/

Here is what I have so far
[image]

```css
.main-box{
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.data-right-bottom ul li{
margin: 10px;
list-style-type: none;
}
.data-right-bottom  ul li span{
  width: 200px;
  display: flex;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-box">

<div class="data-right-bottom">
                <ul>
                    <li style="display: none;">
                        <span>Total wrapping (tax incl.)</span>
                        <span id="total_wrapping_right" class="total_wrapping_right">0,00 zł</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Total products (tax incl.)</span>
                        <span id="total_product_right" class="total_product_wt_right">210,00 zł</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Total shipping (tax incl.)</span>
                        <span class="total_shipping_right">
                
               12,00 zł
                    
               </span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="order-subtotal">
                        <span>Total (tax excl.)</span>
                        <span class="total_price_without_tax_right">182,73 zł</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="order-discounts" style="display:none">
                        <span>Total discounts</span>
                        <span class="total_discount_right">0,00 zł</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="order-tax">
                        <span>Total tax</span>
                        <span class="total_tax_right">39,27 zł</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="order-total">
                        <span>Total</span>
                        <span class="total_price_right">222,00 zł</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

<div class="data-right-bottom">
                <ul>
                    <li style="display: none;">
                        <span>Total wrapping (tax incl.)</span>
                        <span id="total_wrapping_right" class="total_wrapping_right">0,00 zł</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Total products (tax incl.)</span>
                        <span id="total_product_right" class="total_product_wt_right">210,00 zł</span>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <span>Total shipping (tax incl.)</span>
                        <span class="total_shipping_right">
                
               12,00 zł
                    
               </span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="order-subtotal">
                        <span>Total (tax excl.)</span>
                        <span class="total_price_without_tax_right">182,73 zł</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="order-discounts" style="display:none">
                        <span>Total discounts</span>
                        <span class="total_discount_right">0,00 zł</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="order-tax">
                        <span>Total tax</span>
                        <span class="total_tax_right">39,27 zł</span>
                    </li>
                    <li class="order-total">
                        <span>Total</span>
                        <span class="total_price_right">222,00 zł</span>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            
            </div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5fJ4.png
what am I missing in my code to get what I want? any help will be apreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add `display: flex` to the parent of what you are wanting to display as a flex item (in this case the `<li>`), and then add the property `flex: 1 0 0` to the span.

https://jsfiddle.net/vr1c8tgo/

```css
.data-right-bottom ul li{
    margin: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
    display:flex;
}
.data-right-bottom  ul li span{
    width: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Hii Robert can you expalin what does flex 1 0 0  mean?

Comment: Hi, it is shorthand for Flex-Grow, Flex-Shrink and Flex-Basis.

Comment: A really good explanation is available here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: thank so much for the link real help ,  How can I add a space between spans in that list ?

Comment: I think you would use margins/padding on the span. Off the top of my head can’t remember how flex reacts with margins but it should be ok?

Comment: I triend applying margin to ...ul li span but does not work well it pushess everything

Comment: aah got it using margin by adding id to  one span the same for all list , thanks for help